# Windows should display warning when on battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, power-management

I have purchased my first laptop recently. But, the problem is many times I forgot to connect it to power supply. Due, to which all of my battery get exhausted and I get warning when it is only 10% left. I have found the option of selecting low battery level. But, I am looking for some notification (can be beep) which should display after every 10% consumption of battery. Is it possible to do so? And how can I do this?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: My OS is Windows 7

Comment: I hope my replay is what you needed

Comment: Sorry, I want the system to beep regularly after a fixed interval.